# If a CNF contains only Horn and Xor clauses, then what is the complexity of determining Satisfiability?

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, satisfiability, sat-solvers

If a CNF contains only Horn and Xor clauses, and does not contain clauses of other types, then can its Satisfiability be determined in polynomial time?

Comment: What do you think? Have you tried applying Schaeffer's theorem to the bounded width case?

Comment: Have you tried either coming up with an algorithm or showing that the problem is NP-complete?

Comment: @Yuval Filmus - I have to admit that I am very new to this field, as a result not aware of Schaeffer's theorem. The problem that motivated my question is from a CSP that has continuous variables, whose feasibility is reducible to a SAT. I have been unsuccessful in resolving its complexity with the problem described in CSP form, but have no clue on how to go about this in SAT form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Using XOR clauses you can express "$x = \lnot y$", and this allows you to simulate general clauses by Horn clauses.

Comment: So I guess it should be NP complete.

Comment: Yes, that's the conclusion.